# Prestashop transferring on different domain

Tags: prestashop

I was creating a Prestashop website on my development domain, and now when it's done, i wanted to transfer it to the new, official domain.

However, When doing so, I came across an error i couldn't solve. Page just loaded an error saying

"Error: "install" directory is missing",

and in error.log, there was this:

[error] [client ] PHP Warning:  realpath(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 1044 is not allowed to access /var/www/domain.com/www owned by uid 0 in /var/www/domain.com/www/config/defines.inc.php on line 69

[error] [client ] PHP Warning:  realpath(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 1044 is not allowed to access /var/www/domain.com/www owned by uid 0 in /var/www/domain.com/www/config/defines.inc.php on line 66

On those lines is this:

define('_PS_ROOT_DIR_', realpath($currentDir.'/..'));

define('_PS_CORE_DIR_', realpath($currentDir.'/..'));

Anyone knows how to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP configuration on your server is too restrictive.
You can read explanations regarding this error in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php).

You can try to put this line of code at the end of your .htaccess file

```
php_value  safe_mode_gid  true
```

If it doesn't work you can try this code :

```
php_value  safe_mode_include_dir  /var/www/domain.com/www
```

If none of this two solutions works, this might mean that you need to edit your php.ini or httpd.conf files due to some restrictions on your apache configuration. You might ask your hosting provider how to disable `PHP SAFE MODE`.